# LP relaxation of ILP and the ILP have the same optimal value

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, binary-programming

I have an ILP (all variables are binary) and on several instances I’ve observed that its optimal value coincides with the LP relaxation optimal value.

The LP relaxation is not integral for fractional optimal solutions are attained.

I’d like to prove that what I have observed is actually true. I suppose I’ll have to check some conditions on the polytope of the relaxation as well as the objective function, but I do not know where to start.

I’ve been trying to search for some results in these kind of problems, but I’ve found none.
Has someone of you faced this problem (or a similar one)? Or do you know some result or some idea on how to prove this type of statement?

Comment: A linear function attains its maximum and minimum at extreme points (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer_maximum_principle). In many cases (such as yours), these extreme points are integral, which implies that the optimal value of the LP relaxation and the original ILP coincide.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said, the polytope that defines the LP relaxation is not integral. Therefore that type of argument is not useful in this case. 
What I’d like to find is a line of arguments to conclude that the polytope of optimal solutions always has an integral point on it.

Comment: It would be useful to post your actual ILP in your question.